# Typescript - JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using React Native + Typescript app and getting an error on Wrapper variable.

```
JSX element type 'Wrapper' does not have any construct or call signatures.  TS2604
```

```
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

export function BasicLayout({ children, isLoggedIn, isActualUser, scrollable = true }: Props) {
  const Wrapper = scrollable ? ScrollView : View;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {!isLoggedIn || !isActualUser ? <HeaderWrapper /> : <HeaderPrivate />}
      <Wrapper style={styles.container} >
        {children}
        <FooterLinks />
        <FooterCopyright />
      </Wrapper>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you show me the full code ,(the full component) , I want to see the typescript construct that you've made for Wrapper Component

Comment: @Coderboi it's functional component, i updated the post

Comment: You're importing `StyleSheet` but using `ScrollView`. Seems `ScrollView` is not defined

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28631 try this to see if work for you

Comment: @Fyodor no it's defined, i just did not write there

Comment: @TonyNgo not sure what to try from there, already saw